# Unable to Parse property name "description" in Json file in realm swift

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, xcode, realm

I am trying to parse JSON through realm Swift Here is my Json. response

```
{
    code = 1;
    data =     {
        subjects =         (
                        {
                code = 786;
                description = "not a good deal";
                id = 13;
                name = "Mechine Learning in iOS";
            }
        );
    };
    message = success;
}
```

And here it is my swift file to parse this json.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm
class Subject: Object
{
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var code: String!
    @objc dynamic var name: String!
    @objc dynamic var description: String!

        override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
}
```

We know that `description` is keyword in swift, so it shows this error:

```
Getter for 'description' with Objective-C selector 'description' conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector.
```

Is there any way to parse `description` here, without using `key value` explicitly?

Comment: Sounds like you have a damaged installer file. Try re-downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

use another parameter for description (myDescription) and override init

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm
class Subject: Object{
func parseDescription(data : [String: Any]) {

    guard let desc:String = data["description"] as? String else{
        return
    }

    myDescription = desc
}
override init(value: Any) {
    super.init(value: value)
    guard let data: [String: Any] = value as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    parseDescription(data: data)
}

required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    guard let data: [String: Any] = value as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    parseDescription(data: data)

}

@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var code: String!
@objc dynamic var name: String!
@objc dynamic var myDescription: String!

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Found 2 soutions:

1. Update the date of your machine
2. Use alternate USB port

To update the datetime of your machine you can open Utilities->Terminal in the installer, check the current datetime with the command `date` and if it is wrong use the command `ntpdate -u time.apple.com`

> Note that you has to be connected to the internet or use the command date with timestamp to set the datetime manually